# Profiling C++ code used by MEX functions in MATLAB on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, matlab, profiling, mex

So I've read a few of these posts on stack overflow, but most have to do with profiling MEX functions on Linux (with valgrind/gprof) or on Windows with Visual Studio.

I have a large piece of software, that is written in C++, compiled to a MEX binary file, and also has MEX functions called from C++ code within MATLAB scripts.

I want to profile this application, and figure out what is slowing down the application or what functions I need to speed up, but since it's so large I don't really know where to start. This is why I wanted a profiler to figure out some of the issues for me.

The only profiler I could really find that would work on OSX is instruments. The problem is I can't really figure out how to use it correctly. If I profile the binary file, it doesn't give me any relevant information (mostly just gives me hex values of the application initializing). If I call the actual script (.m) file, it gives me the same kind of information, for example:

`dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*)`

Is the function called under the `Main thread` (which is the only thread) within instruments. Is there something I should be doing to profile the application, or is there another profiler I can use that will help me understand what is going on?

Comment: Generally you will using a sampling compiler, rather than one that performs instrumentation of the binary. But perhaps not on OSX? To get useful information when profiling, the binary needs to have been compiled with profiling information generated.  I don't know about the compiler you are using, but with gcc it is the `-pg` switch to use gprof.  For Clang, have a look [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#using-sampling-profilers), where the `-gline-tables-only` option is suggested for use with the Linux Perf profiler.

Comment: @chappjc As far as I know, gcc invokes clang on mac osx. I originally thought I could use gprof but apparently it does not work on osx. I should probably just build the project on Linux so I can use gprof :/